# exe and .exe tag

Tags: discussion, support, synonym-request

There are two equal tags. I think [.exe](/questions/tagged/.exe) should be a synonym of [exe](/questions/tagged/exe). I know that [.exe](/questions/tagged/.exe) has much less tags questions, but there are many *`.extension`* tags which are synonyms of *`extension`* tags.

Comment: Why do we even have these tags to begin with?!?!

Comment: I can just guess that there are some cases where the question is about a file extension without the knowledge of the meaning. Ok this does not matter in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All questions tagged with [.exe](/questions/tagged/.exe) have been merged into [exe](/questions/tagged/exe). I don't see how this tag is particularly useful, but there are plenty of other extension tags similar to it, so let's save that for another discussion. If you want to get rid of one, you should get rid of them all.